# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil

Tags: java, mockito, testng, powermockito

I want to use testng + powermock + spring to run test code,my jar version is:

```
powermock = 1.6.2
powermock-module-testng = 1.6.2 
mockito = 1.10.19
testng = 6.8.7
spring = 4.1.1.RELEASE
JDK = 1.8.0
```

And my test code as follows,and not extends AutoBaseTest, can run normal，AutoBaseTest contains
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/test/resources/applicationContext-test.xml"})

```
    @PrepareForTest({test.class}) 


  public class mockTest extends AutoBaseTest {

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {

        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }


    @Test
    public final void test() throws Exception  {
        ......
    }
    }
```

the Error stack ：

```
`FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass springTestContextBeforeTestClass
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.(MockitoException.java:30)
at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.(PluginRegistry.java:12)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.(Plugins.java:11)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.(MockUtil.java:24)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.(MockScanner.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:96)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:35)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:60)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:663)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:415)
at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.injectMocksUsingAnnotationEnabler(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:75)
at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.invoke(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:47)
at test.java.com.sosoPay.servicetest.mockTest_$$jvstb5f_0.springTestContextBeforeTestClass(mockTest$$_jvstb5f_0.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
... 48 more

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod springTestContextAfterTestMethod(public final void test.java.com.sosoPay.servicetest.mockTest.test() throws java.lang.Exception)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.(MockScanner.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:96)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:35)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:60)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:663)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:415)
at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.injectMocksUsingAnnotationEnabler(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:75)
at org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.invoke(PowerMockTestNGMethodHandler.java:47)
at test.java.com.sosoPay.servicetest.mockTest_$$jvstb5f_0.springTestContextAfterTestMethod(mockTest$$_jvstb5f_0.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass springTestContextAfterTestClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.(MockScanner.java:22)`
```

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil ==> lokks like you are missing some dependency.

Comment: mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
  mockito-core-1.10.19.jar
  powermock-api-mockito-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-core-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-api-support-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-reflect-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-module-junit4-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-module-junit4-common-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-module-testng-1.6.2.jar
  powermock-module-testng-common-1.6.2.jar

Comment: Make sure you're following the advice for using TestNG and Powermock together, especially regarding `PowerMockObjectFactory` as explained [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage).  You may find your problem easier to diagnose once the correct factory is used.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar and @stephen-hartley I've also faced with the given issue when I run our PowerMock tests, I still cannot figure out what happened. I think it worked before, but I'm not sure.  As you may see first exception that we have NPE at `(Plugins.java:17)` and I think it's  somehow connected with ClassLoaders. I can get same issue for jUnit module also.

Comment: Is `AutoBaseTest` or one of its ancestors able to extend `PowerMockTestCase`?  I can only reproduce this issue when I don't extend `PowerMockTestCase`.

Comment: @StephenHartley, it's [Mockito bug](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/368). It's recommended to extend the `PowerMockTestCase`, but it is not strict needed.

Answer (score 9):

It's a [defect in Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/368) with loading plugins when context class loader is different from which is used to load PowerMock and Mockito.

It could be fixed in Mockito 2, but as it mentioned in comments

> Not sure we have the build infrastructure to backport the fix on 1.x

For Mockito 1, fix cannot be delivered, so I fixed in in PowerMock and fix will be include in next PowerMock release ([PowerMock 1.6.5](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/milestones/PowerMock%201.6.5)).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. This helped me
Add JMockit.Jar location in VM options under configurations as:

javaagent:C:/.../.../jmockit.jar